# Вывод на экран значений, многопоточность

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Что я делаю неправильно?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void func()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
      std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

1)

```
int main()
{
   std::thread t1(func);
   std::thread t2(t1);
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
   return 0;
}
```

2)

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t(func);
    t.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

Во втором ничего не выводится
В первом кричит на

```
 std::thread t2(t1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
   std::thread t1(func);
   std::thread t2(t1);
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
   return 0;
}
```

Потоки не копируются. Создайте новый поток с той же функцией -

```
   std::thread t2(func);
```

Здесь

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t(func);
    t.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

Вы создали поток, разрешили ему выполняться, и тут же закончили работу программы. Поток - часть программы, он тоже тут же оказывается убит, не успев даже, наверное, запуститься, не то чтоб что-то вывести...

Посмотрите https://ideone.com/ckpRLm и https://ideone.com/UNwYlJ

Comment: ок. спасибо.  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2)); - а можно как то по  дургому  это  написать?

Comment: Это просто задержка на 2 секунды. Можно воспользоваться `sleep`, но зачем? раз ваш компилятор C++11 поддерживает...